# I2C, how do I read from a SPECIFIC register?

Tags: embedded, i2c

My master is an MSP430F169. My slave is an SI514. I have read the data sheets and manuals and all the example code I can find, but I can't find any code for how to read/write from/to a specific register. I know conceptually how it is supposed to work, but I just really need to see a simple example, and I can do everything from there. Here is the code I have (minus all the setup):

```
U0CTL |= MST;                                     
I2CTCTL |= I2CSTT + I2CSTP;
```

// right here is probably where I need to tell the slave where I want to read from, which is address 0x84

```
while ((I2CIFG & RXRDYIFG) == 0);
data_im_reading = I2CDRB;
```

If anyone can tell me how to fill in the gaps in my code, I appreciate it. Again, I have read the data sheets, manuals, and example code, and it just isn't specific enough.

Comment: https://e2e.ti.com/support/microcontrollers/msp430/f/166/t/19452?Source-code-for-MSP430F169-I2C    Link is available here to see related I2C examples.

Comment: _"(minus all the setup)"_ - how do you know that is correct?  It is not clear what you are asking - how to read an I2C register or how to read a register on the  SI514?  If the latter, your code is a long way from that and your attempt shows little effort or understanding of I2C transactions despite the claim _"I know conceptually how it is supposed to work,"_ - clearly not, or if so perhaps you should explain the concept - it would serve you well to have that corrected rather then just given example code you might not understand.  I am sure example code exists all over the internet.

Comment: See section 5.3 "I2C Interface" in the [Si514 Datasheet](https://www.silabs.com/documents/public/data-sheets/Si514.pdf).  Figure 6 shows a read from register operation.